# How to decode weird encryption in script?

Tags: encryption

I run a proxy for the Pirate Bay. I don't think I'm allowed to link to the script itself but it called "unblocked pirate bay".

And this script doesn't have *normal* code like I know it. It encrypts (?) everything and I'm a little suspicious of it. It looks kind of like this (but with no spaces).

```
eval(
    gzinflate(
        str_rot13(
        base64_decode('')
        )
    )
);
```

And inside the base64_decode is a LONG list of random strings (~8000 characters). Is there a quick and easy way to decode this? So I can see whats going on?

Comment: replace `eval` by some kind of `print`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The answer is right there in your question. Take the scary string, [base64 decode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) it, [ROT13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rot13) it, and then [GZ inflate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) it. When you do that you'll have executable JavaScript code. I suspect it'll be highly obfuscated and not very readable, but it will at least be valid JavaScript.